# Markdown empty lines

Tags: wordpress, markdown

I'm trying to format my text in Markdown, but whatever I do it keeps gobbling up empty lines on WordPress.
(what i mean by that is, i can't create multiple blank lines to separate the content of the blog post, the empty lines i create keep getting merged into one (like when Html ignores white space))

The closest I got was with `\` but, no matter how many `\` I add, the last one is always visible while the rest aren't.

I tried literally everything I found, I spent hours finding the answer, I installed dozens of markdown plugins for WordPress, and neither one of them did anything.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
### Lorem Ipsum


                          ← white space i need


***Lorem Ipsum dolor***
```

```
### Lorem Ipsum
***Lorem Ipsum Dolor***         ← White space i get inside of the wordpress
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "it keeps gobbling up empty lines on WordPress? Please read [ask].

Comment: i edited the question, i hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but your question still isn't clear. Consider adding some examples, please.

Comment: This is the best i can do without ability to post pictures and visual aids.

Comment: "without ability to post pictures and visual aids"—why can't you post pictures? In any case, this is better. Thanks.

Comment: What Markdown library are you using, and how are you using it? You say "I installed dozens of markdown plugins for WordPress, and neither one of them did anything", but we need a _specific_ question here, please.

Comment: i'm using Software called Typora i believe it's using markdown github uses, regardless.
i can't make empty lines  even with wordpress' native blog software. in Html you fix that problem by adding `<br>` tag, but i can't make it work with markdown. (in html for every new empty line that you want to create you add `<br>` tag) i mean there isn't literally anything more specific than that. Anyone who didn't udnerstand the question so far, had to udnerstand it when i mentioned `<br>` tag for Html.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the issue but I will do my best.

Have you tried just putting a single `\` in every empty line. If you put an odd number of `\` in a line then it will make it visible. Lemme know if that works or if I am horribly misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Of course I put only one ' \ ' in every single line, but the one in the last line is always visible, if i put 10 backslashes, that 10th one will be visible. it's infuriating. BUT 9 of them do the job perfectly.

Comment: The problem is that not even single method of escaping white lines works on WordPress.
And I tried every single method I could find `<br>` ; `<br/>` ; ` / ` ; ` \ ` ; ascii white space ; and a lot more, nothing works.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now that is definitely annoying you might need to ask the wordPress support what’s going on it seems as though it’s on their interpreter end. Sorry I can’t help more I’ll do some more digging.

Comment: I spent hours scrapping the web, there is simply nothing that can help, which I didn't already try. Save your time mate, I'll see to contact WordPress support some time tomorrow.